Nginx nginx reverse proxy rewrite part of domain name
Good day,
I want to use nginx to fix some php errors in legacy code) So this is gone be strange one.
I have test1.mydomain.com and test2.mydomain.com and sometimes php back-end routes request to test2 to test1, so i want using nginx place a permanent rewrite in config of test2.mydomain.com so that any url`s with test1 going through it will be changed to test2.
i tried to do simple rewrite, as
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://some-ip;
    real_ip_header          X-Real-IP;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

    proxy_connect_timeout 800s;
    proxy_send_timeout 800s;
    proxy_read_timeout 800s;
    send_timeout 800s;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;

   rewrite ^test1.mydomain.com/(.*)$  https://test2.mydomain.com/$1 break;
    }

but it didn`t work.

If you are trying to change Host to test2.mydomain.com, you could use proxy_set_header Host test2.mydomain.com;
